# android studio2 emulator can't start

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I use an Android Studio 2.0 created a project. When I start AVD, I find AVD emulator can't start.

- I changed the emulator RAM to 768M, but it also failed
- I updated tool, but it's still failing

My SDK manager:
[image: My Android Studio SDK manager tool screenshot]

My log:

```
2016-04-12 22:23:08,478 [3145890]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online. 
2016-04-12 22:32:13,561 [3690973]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2016-04-12 22:44:31,035 [4428447]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online. 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_s, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_s 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_10, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_10 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_one, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_one 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_4, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_4 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\galaxy_nexus, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\galaxy_nexus 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_6, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_6 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_5, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_5 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_7, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_7 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_6p, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_6p 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_9, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_9 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\tv_1080p, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\tv_1080p 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_7_2013, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_7_2013 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_5x, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_5x 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,822 [4477234]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\tv_720p, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\tv_720p 
2016-04-12 22:45:19,955 [4477367]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_5x, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_5x 
2016-04-12 22:45:20,001 [4477413]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_5x, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_5x 
2016-04-12 22:45:20,001 [4477413]   WARN - a.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard - Failed to copy skin directory to D:\android\sdk\skins\nexus_5x, using studio-relative path D:\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_5x
```

Answer (score 0):

today,i just try click android studio "Help>check for update..." ,than updated android SDK Tools 25.1.1 to android SDK Tools 25.1.2. i just try start emulator again it work success! so exciting ..